# Terraform GCP - update existing bucket objects with new kms key

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-kms

I used this code below to encrypt my bucket but it doesn't update existing objects.   Is there a way I could encrypt all the objects in the bucket as well?
Without using gsutil of course, just terraform resource.

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket-tf-creation2" {
  name     = "bucket-tf-creation2"
  location = "australia-southeast1"
  project  = "hallowed-tea-380106"

  encryption {
    default_kms_key_name = "projects/hallowed-tea-380106/locations/australia-southeast1/keyRings/keyringfoo1/cryptoKeys/cryptokeysfoo1"
  }
  force_destroy = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Cloud Storage doesn't presently support automatic migration to a new customer-managed encryption key.